# Strange error: Supersized background slider squeezes pictures in Win 7 IE11 but not in Win 8 IE11

Tags: jquery, background, slider, supersized

I am using Superzised Full Screen Background Slider. Some of the pictures are squeezed in my Windows 7 Internet Explorer 11 see: http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/slideshow/3.2/demo.html

I don't have this problem in Windows 8 IE11. Does anyone knows what this could be?

See picture [here](http://www.janik.cc/supersized-squeezed.jpg)

Comment: I have randomly experienced the exact same problem but can't reproduce it consistently. Have you figured out what the cause is?